# 7z extract through command line throws error "cannot allocate required memory"

Tags: windows, zip, extract, 7zip

I am getting this below error when trying to extract SQL Server ISO file.

> file cab1.cab already exists. Overwrite with
>   1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\cab1.cab? (Y)es / (N)o /
>   (A)lways / (S)kip all / A(u)to rename all / (Q)uit?

When using with -aoa its exracting fine. But why I am getting this error? Replacing the files will cause any problems on the executables?

Comment: I dont see the problem here, did you try saying (Y)es?

Comment: Yes, If I do Yes its working fine. But I am doing the extraction for first time. Then why this Overwrite message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

When using the command

> 7z e <"filename">

it extracts all the files and files inside the subdirectories into the current working directory.

Solution to this is

> 7z x <"filename">

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "can't allocate required memory" error in 7za command line tool in Windows 64bit and the solution was to use the 7zip 64bit installer and use the same command using the installed 7z.exe.

I guess 7za command line tool is 32bit and the file that I was trying to compress was 150GB which is too big and 7zip was trying to allocate more memory than 32bit supports.